# How to emit value in a window of time when keyup event is paused in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have an input search with debounceTime operator, but I want to emit only when the typing event is stopped by the user, in that window of time I will emit the value, if another value is coming it should cancel this new values and waiting for stopped event to emit the new value.

The behavior happened when the I pressed a letter key for a while (one second), after that I erase with backspace emitting the value after pressed not waiting for the new value after backspace event.

```
  Observable.fromEvent(this.emailRef.nativeElement, 'keyup')
  .map((evt: any) => evt.target.value)
  .debounceTime(700)        
  .distinctUntilChanged()
   // emit only when the typing is paused for 1000 ms
  .subscribe((text: string) => this.submit(text));
```

[Link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-observable-form-input-debounce-qneels)

Comment: Add another debounce.....?

Comment: could you please rephrase the last paragraph of the question? it is not obvious, what you are trying to achieve. it seems `debounceTime(700)` already "emits only after 700ms of no type events from user"